# Trying to find a run time error via logcat, do not understand how to read it

Tags: android, runtime-error, logcat

I am having a run time error and cannot figure out where it is.  I looked at logcat and do not understand want I am looking it.  Can someone help me understand what this means so I can figure out where to go to fix the mistake.

```
02-13 10:50:10.868: D/AndroidRuntime(529): Shutting down VM
02-13 10:50:10.868: W/dalvikvm(529): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-13 10:50:10.948: E/AndroidRuntime(529): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-13 10:50:10.948: E/AndroidRuntime(529): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.signalsetapp/com.signalsetapp.SignalSetMobileAppActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.signalsetapp.SignalSetMobileAppActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.signalsetapp-2.apk]
02-13 10:50:10.948: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1544)
02-13 10:50:10.948: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
02-13 10:50:10.948: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-13 10:50:10.948: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
02-13 10:50:10.948: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-13 10:50:10.948: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-13 10:50:10.948: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
02-13 10:50:10.948: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 10:50:10.948: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-13 10:50:10.948: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-13 10:50:10.948: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-13 10:50:10.948: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-13 10:50:10.948: E/AndroidRuntime(529): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.signalsetapp.SignalSetMobileAppActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.signalsetapp-2.apk]
02-13 10:50:10.948: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
02-13 10:50:10.948: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
02-13 10:50:10.948: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
02-13 10:50:10.948: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
02-13 10:50:10.948: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1536)
02-13 10:50:10.948: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  ... 11 more
02-13 10:50:14.748: I/Process(529): Sending signal. PID: 529 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Its all about `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:`..

Comment: When does the error occur? At startup? When you try to start another activity?

Comment: If I am reading this right, the error is in SignalSetMobileAppActivity

Comment: If it happens at startup, the problem is probably in your AndroidManifest.xml. See Binyamin's answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dalvik cannot instantiate the class SignalSetMobileAppActivity:

```
Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.signalsetapp/com.signalsetapp.SignalSetMobileAppActivity}:
```

because, it cannot find the class:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.signalsetapp.SignalSetMobileAppActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.signalsetapp-2.apk]
```

This usually happens when you don't declare the activity in the manifest. Something like that:

```
<activity android:name="com.signalsetapp.SignalSetMobileAppActivity" />
```

Comment: This is in my manifest    <activity
            android:name=".SignalSetMobileAppActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

Comment: Is the app installed on SD card by any chance? have you tried to clean and rebuild the project?

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.signalsetapp/com.signalsetapp.SignalSetMobileAppActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.signalsetapp.SignalSetMobileAppActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.signalsetapp-2.apk]
```

Android cannot find *com.signalsetapp.SignalSetMobileAppActivity* which is declared in your manifest as an Activity.